# Getting error from Pandas DataFrame.to_sql while loading a file to Informix Database

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyodbc, informix

I am getting an error while loading a file using Pandas Dataframe's `to_sql` method on an Informix Database. I am able to connect to the Informix database and execute the select query using the `read_sql_query` method like so:

```
df = pd.read_sql_query(query,con)
```

But the code below is throwing an error, and I can't figure out why:

```
con = pyodbc.connect(constr, autocommit=True) 
file ='/home/webload/rajesh.txt' 
df = pd.read_csv(file, sep="\t") 
pd.DataFrame.to_sql(name='customers', schema='informix', con=con, if_exists='append', index=False )
```

This is the error I'm receiving:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "connect1.py", line 42, in <module>
    pd.DataFrame.to_sql(name='customers', schema='informix',con=con, if_exists='append', index=False  )
TypeError: to_sql() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'
```

Comment: The `to_sql` method is intended to be invoked on an existing `DataFrame` object, so `pd.DataFrame.to_sql` makes no sense. You really want to do `df.to_sql(...)` so pandas knows which DataFrame you want to upload.

Comment: @gordthompson  Getting this error now:  My  database is Informix  
 'error' Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/webload/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1431, in execute
    cur.execute(*args)
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42S02', '[42S02] [Informix][Informix ODBC Driver][Informix]The specified table (sqlite_master) is not in the database. (-206) (SQLPrepare)')

Comment: @gordthompson I think ** to_sql**  cannot be used for Informix. Is there a  way to load into informix DB i